# Safe way to handle closure of sockets managed by epoll

Tags: linux, sockets

Using epoll_wait to manage multiple connections using multiple threads, there is a risk trying to release custom data associated with a closed socket.

Consider the following scenario, where T is the custom data :

1. Data is received,
2. Because of 1, thread A deblocks from epoll_wait and processes the event (access T)
3. At same time, another thread B, wants to close the connection

Thread B can't assume that T can be safely deleted, eventhough the call to close will immediatly remove the socket from the epoll.

I had the following standard idea :

Maintain a variable within T that gets incremented each time a call to write/read returns EAGAIN, and gets decremented each time the socket is ready.
When close is called, wait for that variable to go down to zero before deleting T.
The issue I experienced is that if close is called, epoll_wait does not return an indication of a cancellation of previous calls to arm the socket.

Anybody had this same problem ? How did you managed to overcome it ?

Comment: I have the exact same problem and can't think of good solution yet. I also found the article of the accepted answer, but that is hardly an answer since the patch wasn't accepted into the kernel (and according to a comment there isn't good enough as solution). May I ask what you eventually did yourself to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many research, I found this recent and remarkable article : 
http://lwn.net/Articles/520012/
Basically it acknowledge the issue I am describing and speaks about a possible future patch to Linux kernel that allows to extend the epoll API in a way that solves the issue.

The extension bring a new command called : EPOLL_CTL_DISABLE.
When it is issued, and by means of return value, the calling thread will know if some other thread has just been deblocked from epoll_wait upon same socket.
This can help know the safe moment of closure and release of custom data.

Comment: Do you know a fate of this command? Is it still available in latest kernels? - I can't find it in 3.11.

Comment: I still do not know.. But I have a server to be deployed on Jan 1st, I surely have to revisit this, then I shall inform you.

Comment: Just a warning that this problem is way more complicated than it looks. The EPOLL_CTL_DISABLE patch never made it into the kernel, but even if it did it is not enough, alone, to solve the problem. I.e. even if you can detect that another thread may be processing an event, you still need some way to reliably mark that it should be deleted. You can't count uses as you describe in your question since you never know whether a count > 0 means that processing has finished or hasn't yet begun.

Answer (score 4):

At least three possible ways here:

- Do not use threads, simple and clean, and *usually* works.
- Have a dedicated thread do all file descriptor polling and publish *events* to a pool of worker threads that do actual I/O and processing.
- Have one [`epoll(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html) instance per thread, so threads manage non-intersecting sets of descriptors, with the exception of maybe the listening socket(s) to get these sets populated, and some control mechanism like [`eventfd(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/eventfd.2.html), or self-[`pipe(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html) to be able to shutdown the whole rig cleanly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Each of these modifications avoid the problem by scarifying efficiency. In particular, method 3 is only good under the assumption that the activity of each thread is the same.

Comment: You have some distorted notion of "efficiency" then. You might mean "generality" here, maybe, but you have to pay the price somewhere. E.g. if you access your event structure from multiple thread, you need to protect it from races (mutex, atomic var, or something) - and that's far from "efficient" in the accepted sense of the word.

Comment: The probability that the multiple threads will access the same structure is very low given the intended number of connections to be treated at same time. So making a lock at that level will not decrease performance. Changing the threading model to solve the issue of safe closure, will kill performance for no proportional reason. Sorry, but thanks for your endeavours and good will to help.

Comment: The only thing I'm saying here is that there is *always* more then one way to do it. And, at the end, correctness is way more important then "performance".

Comment: Method one leads to "fd starvation" is unacceptable. Method two isn't a solution at all: then the thread worker will need to delete the FileDescriptor object, leading to the exact problem that we try to solve (see the article pointed to by the accepted answer), method three is basically the same as method 1 and leads to starvation; except that you divided the fd's over multiple epoll_wait() calls.

Comment: You people keep missing the point - the API has limitations, so work around them. The (not exactly correct) statements in the last comment just show how narrow minded your brute-force approach is.